# Finding a way to use subtraction between all elements in a function in Python

Tags: python, arrays, arraylist, subtraction

I am currently making a simple calculator that will be used in continually performing calculations. It is menu-driven so I can't really interchange between different operations until the end when I can append the answer and select a different operation (wish I could figure that out, maybe another time). One of my options I have need for my menu is subtraction.

I managed to get it to work so far with addition and multiplication. Below is a function that stores input as elements in my array:

Is there a way to create a reverse running total by subtracting the running total by the next element input? Also, is it possible to make numbers go negative in the reverse running total and elements input?

TL;DR I would like to subtract between each list element while making a running total. If possible, I need a way to make negative numbers work as well for input and reverse running total, these are all floating numbers, not integers.

```
def number_list(operator_item, previous_total): 
    number_list = []
    counter = 1
    print("Enter values, enter '=' to create final answer and copy answer")
    while number_list != "=":         
        try:
            list_value = float(input())
        except ValueError: 
            sentinel_value = input("Type '=' again to finalize calculation, copy answer, and return to menu to select another operation\n") 
            if sentinel_value == "=":
                copy(running_total)
                return running_total

            else:
                 print("Invalid option")
            menu_selection() #This is irrelevant

        number_list.append(list_value)
        counter += 1

        if operator_item == "+":
            running_total = addition(number_list)
            print("Current sum:", running_total + ans)

#Using function as an example. Subtraction will be a separate function as well
def addition(number_array):
    total = sum(number_array)
    return total
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I think that `itertools.accumulate` satisfies your needs for any operation:

```
import itertools
import operator

nums = [5, 3, 4, 2, 1]

# Addition
print(list(itertools.accumulate(nums, operator.add)))
# [5, 8, 12, 14, 15]

# Subtraction
print(list(itertools.accumulate(nums, operator.sub)))
# [5, 2, -2, -4, -5]

# Multiplication
print(list(itertools.accumulate(nums, operator.mul)))
# [5, 15, 60, 120, 120]
```

There are many other operations defined in `operator`. If you don't need the intermediate results, use `functools.reduce` instead. For instance, subtraction:

```
import functools
import operator

nums = [5, 3, 4, 2, 1]

print(functools.reduce(operator.sub, nums))
# -5
```

Comment: Hey that helps quite a bit. The only issue I have is I only want to display the current element.

So if I subtract 3 from 5, it would only display 2 (the second element). When the displays run right now, it will show all the elements up to the current one.

Comment: Can you demonstrate how to apply functools.reduce to the total? The final element is what I want to display, without the brackets

Comment: @CodyTapp First of all, it is very easy to access the last element; just use `-1` as the index. Anyway, I made an edit demonstrating `functools.reduce`.